# Installing Libraries from docker with pip install, i get error on container

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, pip

I have a docker file, when I run docker-compose build app this work fine, When I enter to bash: `docker exec -it project_1 /bin/bash` and try to run the following command `python main.py` I get the following error:

```
 File "main.py", line 2, in <module>
    import pandas as pd
    ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pandas'
```

docker file:

```
FROM python:3

ADD .   /var/projects/app
WORKDIR /var/projects/app
COPY requirements.txt ./
RUN chown -R webapp /var/projects/ && chmod -R u+rX /var/projects/
RUN pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install --no-cache-dir -r requirements.txt
COPY . .

CMD [ "python", "./main.py" ]
EXPOSE 8004
```

dokcer-compose.yml:

```
  version: '3.4'
volumes:
  app:
    driver: "local"
services:
    app:
      build:
        context: ./
        dockerfile: Dockerfile
      ports:
        - "8004:8004"
      volumes:
        - "./:/var/projects/app"
```

requierements.txt

```
numpy==1.18
pandas==1.0.1
```

what is wrong?

Comment: Try to minimize the example by removing all the code which is not necessary for the problem to be still present.

Comment: Works for me. One needs just either to remove _chown_ or add `RUN useradd webapp` to make docker build. When I fixed in any of these ways docker runs. Assuming _main.py_ has one line: `import pandas as pd`.

Answer (score 0):

If you're running docker-compose then you should use `docker-compose exec <service_name> /bin/bash -l` instead of the docker exec command. docker exec will run your bash prompt inside a new container, whereas docker-compose will find the already running container (which presumably has all your dependencies)